# Why does my data not update in component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have simple component like

```
<my-comp :item="item"></my-comp>

// in script
components: {
   MyComp 
},
data : {
   item: 'hello
}
```

When value for data item is assigned only first time is show but updated value does not change. I use this example I find online. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` needs to be a function, for one.  `data () { return { ... } }`. Your question and code is very vague, post more info for people to better help you.